# sqlalchemy two base class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want my subclass inherit from two base class

```
from sqlalchemy import * 
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import as_declarative,declared_attr,AbstractConcreteBase
import re
import datetime
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship,Session, relationship, backref,Mapper

def camel_case_split(identifier):
    matches = re.finditer('.+?(?:(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|$)', identifier)
    return [m.group(0) for m in matches]

@as_declarative()
class ModelBase1(object):
"""
"""
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
       name_list=camel_case_split(cls.__name__)
       return '_'.join([s.lower() for s in name_list])
    id=Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

@as_declarative()
class ModelBase2(object):
"""
"""
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        name_list=camel_case_split(cls.__name__)
        return '_'.join([s.lower() for s in name_list])

    id=Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name=Column(String(32))

class User(ModelBase2):
'''
'''
    group_id=Column(String(32),ForeignKey('channel.id'),nullable=True)
    group=relationship('UserGroup',foreign_keys=[group_id], backref='users')

class UserGroup(ModelBase1):
    group_access=Column(String(32),nullable=True)

if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None:
    user1=User(name='mxin')
    print user1.name
```

when I run this script, there is an error like following:
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper|User|user, expression 'UserGroup' failed to locate a name ("name 'UserGroup' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the  class after both dependent classes have been defined.

it seems user's relationship group can't recogonize UserGroup, when the two class inherit the same base class, the script is correct.

I want to ask what is the problem?

Comment: The two classes do not inherit from the same base class.

Comment: I know, but then the relationship can't work ? it is strange. is there any solution to different base class system? or only one base class

Comment: Only one declarative base, but why are you defining columns on the base anyway? Why can you have `ModelBase1` and 2 be abstract and inherit from the same Base?

Comment: do you mean create Mixin class contains different common columns?  if I create Mixin, then my subclasses  will inherit from mutilclass. what is your meaning  to set ModelBase1 to be abstract?

Comment: [`__abstract__`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#abstract)

Comment: thank you very much